# Web worker not working html5

Tags: html, gif, animated-gif

i have recently started to program in html5,

My friend asked me to build him a youtube video to gif, i have zero idea how to do this, he wants it to sit in his computer (with a web server).

I am looked around in google for few hours before coming in this time because i know this is not google.

So, i found this code - http://techslides.com/demos/video/generate-animatedgif.html, on hes website its working like a charem right? so. he said, copy this template to your web server and it will work.

Well, i did just that - look what happnd -

```
w.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Worker is not defined
```

IF NEEDED, i can upload and share my link here if needed. But i will be really happy if someone can tell me what am i doing worng or give me another web that can create gifs ( that you can download the html and host in your own server).

Ty very much, please. i know this is not the reguler qustion in stackoverflow, but please dont close this theard, i ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that web workers can only work if you create a file for them,

So, my answer is simple. I created a w.js file with the code inside, and it works.

Good day all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this line of code 
var worker = new Worker('w.js');

in your html file

Comment: Yes i do, and again, you are most welcome to see, its in the link i have linked here.